# JSONserialization error

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am pulling data from a php script that generates a json array. After an iOS update my jsonserialization crashes the app. The json should be well formed according to jsonformatter.org and freeformatter.com/json-validator.html (conforms to RFC4627).
Here is the code. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
func parseJSON() {

    var jsonResult: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    do{
        jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self.data as Data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSMutableArray

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)

    }

    var jsonElement: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
    let locations: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count
    {

        jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

        let location = LocationModel()

        //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
        if let id = jsonElement["id"] as? String,
            let oprettelsesdato = jsonElement["oprettelsesdato"] as? String,
            let overskrift = jsonElement["overskrift"] as? String,
            let address = jsonElement["address"] as? String,
            let intro = jsonElement["intro"] as? String,
            let email = jsonElement["email"] as? String,
            let tlf = jsonElement["tlf"] as? String,
            let annonce = jsonElement["annonce"] as? String,
            let journalnr = jsonElement["journal"] as? String
        {

            location.id = id
            location.oprettelsesdato = oprettelsesdato
            location.overskrift = overskrift
            location.address = address
            location.intro = intro
            location.email = email
            location.tlf = tlf
            location.annonce = annonce
            location.journalnr = journalnr


        }

        locations.add(location)

    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
        //print("Check home")
        self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(locations)

    })
}
```

Crashlog:

```
objc[1285]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x11799a998) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x1177bc880). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x105f1ed88) to 'NSMutableArray' (0x105f1ee50).
```

**UPDATE**
I am now using vadians solution, however, instead of self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(locations), I use self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(locations as NSArray).

However, all jsonElements are now nil. It gets the correct number of elements in the array but if I print it all the values are nil:

```
(
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil",
"id: nil, oprettelsesdato: nil, overskrift: nil, address: nil, journalnr: nil"
)
```

Here is where I try to retrieve the data.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let item: LocationModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! LocationModel
    let cellIdentifier: String = "BasicCell"
    let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!



    //myCell.detailTextLabel!.text = item.oprettelsesdato
    myCell.textLabel!.text = item.overskrift
    myCell.textLabel!.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myCell.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    myCell.textLabel!.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myCell.topAnchor).isActive = true
    myCell.textLabel!.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myCell.heightAnchor,
                                                multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
    myCell.textLabel!.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myCell.heightAnchor,
                                                multiplier: 0.8).isActive = true


    //print(item.id)  <-returns nil
    //print(item.oprettelsesdato)  <-returns nil
    //print(item.overskrift)  <-returns nil
    extralabel!.text = item.oprettelsesdato  // <-This is where the error is thrown
    extralabel!.textColor =  UIColor.white
    myCell.contentView.addSubview(extralabel!)

//some more stuff...
}
```

Error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Not sure what is going wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you show your crash log?

Comment: jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self.data as Data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSMutableArray changing this line to jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self.data as Data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? NSMutableArray will work

Comment: Simple suggestion. **Do not - never - use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift**. They are not related to Swift collection types and cause all your problems.

Comment: Your new question seems to be completely different than the original one, so you should better start a new thread. Anyway, the result depends on the JSON text before converting to the array of `LocationModel`, you should show the original JSON text (at lease containing one full element).

Comment: Thanks! I have asked the question in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177591/parsing-a-json-array-returns-empty-elements-in-swift/42177685#42177685

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is critical for your issue is this part `as! NSMutableArray` in the line:

```
jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self.data as Data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSMutableArray
```

Even in older iOS's, converting the result of `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` to `NSMutableArray` is **NOT a guaranteed operation** (when you do not specify the `.mutableContainers` option).

Seeing your whole code, you are not mutating `jsonResult`, so you can use a simple `NSArray` rather than `NSMutableArray`:

```
    var jsonResult: NSArray = NSArray()

    do{
        jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self.data as Data) as! NSArray

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)

    }
```

---

I recommend you to use Swift types, such as `Data`, `Array` or `Dictionary`, rather than `NSData`, `NSArray` (`NSMutableArray`) or `NSDictionary`. But that is not critical in your case.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the error at this point. I think I've got an empty element in the json array and I think that is throwing further errors down the line. The json array is pretty large so not very easy to check. But thanks for the help!

Comment: @user1378824, I see. Hope you can solve your issue soon, or we can help you solve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Please let me repeat my comment:

## Do not - never - use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift.

They are not related to Swift collection types and cause all your problems.
The `var` keyword makes any Swift object mutable, very easy to use. Apart from that the received array is not mutated at all in your code.

Sadly the *half knowledge tutorials* which suggest `NSMutable...` will never die off :/

In Swift 3

- a JSON dictionary is `[String:Any]`
- a JSON array is `[[String:Any]]` or `[Any]`

Since the JSON object is supposed to be  an array `.allowframents` is pretty useless.

So:

```
func parseJSON() {

    var jsonResult = [[String:Any]]()

    do{
        jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self.data as Data, options:[]) as! [[String:Any]]

    } catch {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    var locations = [LocationModel]()

    for jsonElement in jsonResult { // no ugly C-style index based loops!

        let location = LocationModel()

        //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
        if let id = jsonElement["id"] as? String,
            let oprettelsesdato = jsonElement["oprettelsesdato"] as? String,
            let overskrift = jsonElement["overskrift"] as? String,
            let address = jsonElement["address"] as? String,
            let intro = jsonElement["intro"] as? String,
            let email = jsonElement["email"] as? String,
            let tlf = jsonElement["tlf"] as? String,
            let annonce = jsonElement["annonce"] as? String,
            let journalnr = jsonElement["journal"] as? String
        {

            location.id = id
            location.oprettelsesdato = oprettelsesdato
            location.overskrift = overskrift
            location.address = address
            location.intro = intro
            location.email = email
            location.tlf = tlf
            location.annonce = annonce
            location.journalnr = journalnr


        }

        locations.append(location)

    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //print("Check home")
        self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(locations)
    }
}
```

Note: If `jsonElement` contains only strings you can even cast the dictionary to `[String:String]` and get rid of **all** `as? String` casts.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest creating an optional init method that takes json and attempts to create a `LocationModel`.

```
struct LocationModel {

    var id: String
    var oprettelsesdato: String
    var overskrift: String
    var address: String
    var intro: String
    var email: String
    var tlf: String
    var annonce: String
    var journalnr: String

    init?(json: [String:Any]) {

        guard
            let id = json["id"] as? String,
            let oprettelsesdato = json["oprettelsesdato"] as? String,
            let overskrift = json["overskrift"] as? String,
            let address = json["address"] as? String,
            let intro = json["intro"] as? String,
            let email = json["email"] as? String,
            let tlf = json["tlf"] as? String,
            let annonce = json["annonce"] as? String,
            let journalnr = json["journal"] as? String else { return }

        self.id = id
        self.oprettelsesdato = oprettelsesdato
        self.overskrift = overskrift
        self.address = address
        self.intro = intro
        self.email = email
        self.tlf = tlf
        self.annonce = annonce
        self.journalnr = journalnr
    }
}
```

Then, in the `parseJSON` function, rather than using `NSMutableArray`, you can use `[LocationModel]`. That way we can directly `flatMap` the array of json elements (`[[String:Any]]`) to `[LocationModel]` using `json.flatMap { LocationModel(json: $0) }`.

```
func parseJSON() {

    var locations = [LocationModel]()

    do{
        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: []) as? [[String:Any]] {
            locations = json.flatMap { LocationModel(json: $0) }
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(locations)
    }
}
```